# "Getting odoo error while deploying ,anybody help"

Tags: odoo

Below error is being encountered when deploying the code

```
File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/auth_crypt/models/res_users.py", line 54, in check_credentials
self.env.cr.execute(\'SELECT password, password_crypt FROM res_users WHERE id=%s AND active\', (self.env.uid,))
File "/opt/odoo/odoo-latest/odoo/sql_db.py", line 154, in wrapper
return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/odoo/odoo-latest/odoo/sql_db.py", line 231, in execute
res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: integer = boolean
LINE 1: ...T password, password_crypt FROM res_users WHERE id=false AND...
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: Do you have your custom code that you deployed? We can't help you if you don't show us your code or what you're trying to do.

Comment: How did you get this error did you use XML-RPC call somewhere